# Redirect if match two conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for a solution to this case via htaccess - If it finds an address with the following structure:
https://www.example.com/(en|ro|ru and etc.)/page.html

To redirect them to the same address without en, ro or ru and without .html .

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried something like that but it is totally wrong in my opinion:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (ro|ru|en)\(.*).html
RewriteRule ^(ro|ru|en)\(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?:en|es)\/(.*)(.*\.html) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can test the result [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=bdf935d3-5eef-5c33-b45c-ba7762263c75) and check the regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/sJcuMe/1).

Comment: Thank you very much, Alfa! I appreciate it!